# Postman [POST] request body is not parsing correctly

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, postman, aws-api-gateway, serverless

So I'm trying to enable the post method to my AWS Lambda function that is connected to the AWS API Gateway. The lambda function is created from one of the examples from [serverless-chrome](https://github.com/adieuadieu/serverless-chrome). (The pdf function)

I'm trying to print the event variable to get the body sent via POST request using Postman.
[My Post Body http://joxi.ru/Drl1qPKfvg6Bjm](http://joxi.ru/Drl1qPKfvg6Bjm)
but when I watch the logs in CloudWatch, I get an output like this:

```
"body":"dXJsPWh0dHAlM0ElMkYlMkZ3d3cuYXBhcnRtZW50ZGF0YS5
pbyUyRmRhc2hib2FyZCUyRnR4LWhvJTJGY2hhbmdlLXJlcG9ydCZsYW
5kc2NhcGU9dHJ1ZSZkaXNwbGF5SGVhZGVyRm9vdGVyPXRydWUmcHJpb
nRCYWNrZ3JvdW5kPXRydWUmc2NhbGU9MSZwYXBlcldpZHRoPTgmcGFw
ZXJIZWlnaHQ9MTEmbWFyZ2luVG9wPTAuMiZtYXJnaW5Cb3R0b209MC4
yJm1hcmdpbkxlZnQ9MC4yJm1hcmdpblJpZ2h0PTAuMg=="
```

What should I do in this situation? Is it because of the ContentType variable sent [POST headers http://joxi.ru/RmzLaOBU0e3PKA](http://joxi.ru/RmzLaOBU0e3PKA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a base64 string.

You can convert that into a `Buffer` object.

From here you have many options. I recommend the following:

1. Upload the `Buffer` object to S3, get the link to S3, and return the link as your output.
2. Upload the `Buffer` object to S3, get the link to S3, and return a temporary redirect (302) pointing to that link in S3.
3. Directly return the `Buffer` object as a file download.